# Switch-off Spring REST Docs Snippets generation when executing unit-tests

Tags: junit, mockmvc, spring-restdocs

Is there any mechanism to switch off snippets generation for Spring REST Docs (say any flag which can be configured) when executing unit-test cases ?

I don't want to make changes at at each unit-test code level here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand why you'd want to do that. REST Docs uses your tests to generate the snippets. If you don't want to generate the snippets, why are you running the tests?

Comment: Do you mean: https://youtu.be/i8TDt7cUG3k?t=1310